# angular 5 404 on refresh

Tags: angular, .htaccess, angular5

The page redirects properly when we click on some link. But if we hit refresh, then will get `404 page not found` error.

I'm stuck with this problem. The application works fine in localhost, but when it is deployed to the server I'm facing this problem.

I know there is something to do with htaccess.

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. We need to add base href as '/' in index.html